# Different behaviour of regex dot?

Tags: regular-expression, wildcards, java, pattern-matching

From this wiki article: [Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

> For example, in the regex `a.`, `a` is a literal character that matches
> just 'a', while `.` is a metacharacter that matches every character
> except a newline. Therefore, this regex matches, for example, `a` , or
> `ax`, or `a0`.

But in a java program I am seeing the dot(`.`) does not match zero occurrence.

```
System.out.println (Pattern.matches("geeksforge.ks", "geeksforgeks"));    //false
System.out.println (Pattern.matches("geeksforge.",  "geeksforge"));       //false
```

1. Which variant of regex is the quoted text (from wiki) referring to?
2. And which variant of regex does java use?

I am aware that there are atleast two variants/syntaxes of regex - POSIX and Perl. But am not sure if there are even more variants and which languages use which of these?

Comment: Here zero means literal `0` character not the empty string.  Perhaps you misunderstood the `'a '` which is literally 'a' 'space'.

Comment: see it now.  Will appreciate if you can comment on which variant "java regex library" is built on.

Answer (score 3):

According to the most recent [Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), the dot (`.`) character matches "Any character (may or may not match line terminators)".  It does not say it will match zero occurrences.  After reading your linked article, it also does not state that the dot will match zero occurrences.

To get your regular expressions to match zero occurrences, you would need to use the asterisk (`*`) or the question mark (`?`) quantifier as those specifically match zero or more occurrences of the character preceding it:

```
System.out.println (Pattern.matches("geeksforge.?ks", "geeksforgeks")); //true
System.out.println (Pattern.matches("geeksforge.?",  "geeksforge"));    //true
System.out.println (Pattern.matches("geeksforge.*ks", "geeksforgeks")); //true
System.out.println (Pattern.matches("geeksforge.*",  "geeksforge"));    //true
```

According to the documentation, `java` regular expressions support both Perl and POSIX syntaxes but you will need to read the documentation for differences and what is and not supported.